# Description-File for physical setup of Multi-Monitors

Tags: hardware, multiple-monitors, virtual-reality

I need machine-readable descriptions for Multi-Monitor and VR Setups, like simple dual-screen computers, [Powerwalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerwall), and [Caves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_Automatic_Virtual_Environment). This description must include the sizes and placements of all outputs (displays or projections) in the physical space.

The far goal is to combine User-(Head)-tracking, device tracking for mobile devices, etc. with multi-display environments.

- The simplest issue is to be aware of the gap between the screens of a multi-monitor setup because of the borders of the display cases.
- The most complex setup would probably be caves with polygonal or curved projection surfaces.

My impression is that every VR-Software out there defines it's own setup-config-crackpot-text-file-format. Is there a *common standard* or *common practice* I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are no common standards in VR (yet) especially the type you take interest in, but you might want to check out [vrui](http://idav.ucdavis.edu/~okreylos/ResDev/Vrui/).

The author of that project understands the need for middle software that would do what you want to do: http://doc-ok.org/?p=123. He also has a great article where he considers that for VR the standard camera model could be changed with great benefits, in a way similar to what you seem to ask for in your question: http://doc-ok.org/?p=27

Maybe, once VR gets some popularity and traction thanks to Oculus and all, a need for standaristaion will rise - there already is one for HMDs, check out the [OSVR project](http://www.osvr.com/). But I dont really see it very probable - CAVEs and Powerwall setups won't be so widespread due to costs involved and space required. Using HMDs will probably be a lot cheaper and more portable/handy.

EDIT: I also found this - http://www.middlevr.com/

Comment: Thanks for that hint on my old question. I will have a look at the project.

Comment: OSVR is designed so that CAVEs and similar multiple-fixed-display setups will be supportable - my background is actually in CAVEs, not HMDs. (and we use a variation on Doc OK's display model...) Right now there isn't a lot of community interest in those setups vs. HMDs, but if you bring it up on the subreddit, mailing list, gitter, you might be able to prompt some movement.

Comment: the gist is that you basically need to describe 3 corners of your screen in world/room space - then you theoretically could generate all the other crazy configs (in which I have some measure of experience :-P) from that.